# Isolating columns with identical values

Tags: r

I am trying to isolate those columns of a dataframe for which all observations have the same value (ignoring NAs). See below for a hypothetical example:

```
ForestName <- rep("Planige", 4)
TreeNumber <- c(1:4)
Height <- c(2.3, 2, 2.1, 2.9)
Type <- c("AA", "AA", NA, "AA")
df <- data.frame(ForestName, TreeNumber, Height, Type)
df
```

The new dataframe should contain ForestName and Type. The columns with unequal values (TreeNumber and Height) should be contained in another dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `unique` and check if this reduces to a single element:

```
df[sapply(df,function(x) length(unique(x[!is.na(x)])))==1]
  ForestName Type
1    Planige   AA
2    Planige   AA
3    Planige <NA>
4    Planige   AA
```

Or test that `all` elements are equal to the first non-`NA`:

```
df[sapply(df, function(x) all(x==na.omit(x)[1],na.rm=T))]
  ForestName Type
1    Planige   AA
2    Planige   AA
3    Planige <NA>
4    Planige   AA
```

Answer (score 1):

Among many other ways, I'm sure:

```
df[,sapply(df,function(x) {length(unique(x[!is.na(x)])) > 1})]

   TreeNumber Height
1          1    2.3
2          2    2.0
3          3    2.1
4          4    2.9
```

And you can negate the `sapply` expression to get the other columns.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more compact approach using the same basic principle

```
 Filter(function(x){length(unique(x[!is.na(x)])) <=1}, df)
```